# search column in data frame for a string value

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to see if a row from the current dataframe is already inside the new dataframe by looking at the string value of `concept`.

But I get

> "TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed".

I've tried other methods that also resulted in different errors, any help would be appreciated!

```
df = pd.read_csv('holder.csv', names = ['concept','frequency'])

newdf = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['concept','frequency'])
for index1, row1 in df.iterrows():
    if newdf.empty:
        row1 = row1.fillna(1)
        newdf = newdf.append(row1,ignore_index=True)
    elif newdf(newdf.concept == row1[0]):
        row1 = row1.fillna(1)


  newdf = newdf.append(row1,ignore_index=True)
```

edit1:
I am trying to seperate the holder.csv (which contains string values and duplicates), such that the end result is another csv file where each entry is unique and stores the frequency of the string value( ie duplicates get added into the frequency)

**holder.csv**

1. decision making
2. authoritative location
3. location
4. decision making

**end.csv**

1. decision making, 2
2. authoritative location, 1
3. location, 1

Comment: Please give an example of `holder.csv` and explain in English what you are trying to do.  The code as written is full of anti-patterns, you'd be better off building a list of tuples if you have to write loops and append row-by-row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC , the end csv can be achieved just by a `groupby`

assuming your column name is `A`

```
    A
0   decision making
1   authoritative location
2   location
3   decision making

>>df.groupby('A').size()


A
authoritative location    1
decision making           2
location                  1
```

Comment: Pleasure..! Happy coding. :)